# How to download files without making application GUI freeze

Tags: java, swing, download

I am creating a application that will download files from URL(My own FTP server). The problem is, when I click the "Download" button, my application will start download, but my application will not have any response when downloading but after downloading everything work fine.

Here is some part of my code

GUI.class

```
b_Download.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                       String username = "Test";
                       startDownloading(username);
            }   
        });

private void startDownload(String username)
    {
        downloader.println("Welcome " + username); //println will show text in a textpane(GUI) and console
        downloader.startDownloading();
    }
```

Downloader.class

```
public void startDownloading()
{       
                println("Download jobs started");


                download.downloadLIB();    
}
```

DownloadJob.class

```
public void downloadLIB()
    {
        launcher.println("Start downloading files from server...");
        String libURL = "http://www.example.com/file.jar";
        File libFile = new File("C://file.jar");
        downloadFile(libURL, libFile, "file.jar");
    }
public void downloadFile(String url, File path, String fileName)
    {
        InputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream fout = null;
        try
        {
            in = URI.create(url).toURL().openStream();
            fout = new FileOutputStream(path);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            int count;
            while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1)
            {
                fout.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            launcher.println("Cannot download file : " + fileName, e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (in != null)
                try
                {
                    in.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            if(fout != null)
                try
                {
                    fout.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            launcher.println("File " + fileName + " downloaded successfully");
        }
    }
```

When i press the 'Download' button, my textpane show the word 'Welcome Username' then it have no response. But my console will show the word 'Welcome Username', 'Download Jobs started' and 'Start download files from sever...'. After few minutes(when the file finish downloaded, my application will start to have response again...

Comment: Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and pay attention to the section on SwingWorker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swing is a single threaded framework.  That is all interactions and modifications are expected to be executed within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

Anything that blocks this thread will prevent it from processing new events, including, paint requests.

This puts you a bind.  The only way to perform the download and not "freeze" the program is to run in some kind of background thread, but you can't update or modify from this thread, as this must be done from within the context of the EDT.

While there a number of ways to solve this problem, the simplest in your case would probably be to use a `SwingWorker`.

It has the capacity to run in the background (off the EDT), methods to re-sync updates to the EDT (`publish`, `process` and `done`) and provides in build functionality for reporting progress.

For example...

- [Using SwingWorker to add a progress bar in a GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928213/using-swingworker-to-add-a-progress-bar-in-a-gui/14928329#14928329)
- [Progress Bar Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199091/progress-bar-java/15199220#15199220)
- [JProgressBar isn't progressing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020949/jprogressbar-isnt-progressing/12021971#12021971)

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details...

Comment: So you mean I have to use SwingWorker and do the download progress in background?

Comment: Can you show me an example to use SwingWorker in Java? Cuz I am not familiar in < , >

Comment: I did.  They are present in three links I added to the end of the question

Answer (score 0):

You will need to spawn a new `Thread`.

When you send a request to the network, you execute a piece of code that will hang untill it gets what it is looking for, the server. This means that there will be a piece where your apps main thread will not respond to system messages, causing the system to think it has stopped responding.

The solution to this, is to spawn a worker thread, or run a service to handle your network requests.

The Thread will hang while it waits for the server, while your main activity thread can continue to be interacted with by the user.

When the worker thread has completed its task, you will need to call back to your main thread in order to alert the user of the download progress / completion.

Comment: OI! Still relevant! Haha! Really need to pay attention to tags. :D