# Java Progressbar to get running of function

Tags: java

I created a pinging program to ping 5 server. How do I have the progressbar to get run while the progress is being run. When the ping is done the progressbar will be 100%

```
  private void btnGetstatusActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

        try {

            pingserver1();
            pingserver2();
            pingserver3();
            pingserver4();
            pingserver5();

    }     

   public void pingserver1() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");

        System.out.println("Sending Ping Request to " + addr);
        boolean status = addr.isReachable(5000);

    }

....
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of many similar questions. A little searching and a simple read of the JProgressBar tutorial will tell you to use a SwingWorker.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using SwingWorker to add a progress bar in a GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928213/using-swingworker-to-add-a-progress-bar-in-a-gui)

Answer (score 1):

You could create yourself an `SwingWorker`, within the `doInBackground` method, you would execute your `pingserverx` methods.

You could then use the `SwingWorker`s progress API to send notifications about updates to the progress and within the `ProperyChangeListener`, update the UI.

For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928213/using-swingworker-to-add-a-progress-bar-in-a-gui/14928329#14928329) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937997/java-swingworker-thread-to-update-main-gui/16938228#16938228)

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details