# Is there a way to get the percentage a BufferedImage is saved?

Tags: java

I have some code which generates images and saves them.  It does this with a [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) and the images can range from 1x1 all the way to 8000x8000.

I save my BufferedImage using the following code:

```
ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);
```

When I am generating the image it calculates a percentage to show the user.

**How do I get the percentage a BufferedImage is saved?  Also how do I use this percentage to and it to the overall percentage for something else?**

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815494/using-jprogressbar-while-converting-image-to-byte-array) provides an answer to what I want, but I have a hard time understanding it and when I use the code given.  I can not get it to work.

Comment: It's a little complex, but the basic idea is, use `ImageIO.createImageOutputStream` passing it the destination of the image (ie  a `File`, `RandomAccessFile` or `OutputStream`), use `ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("...");` to get an `Iterator` of the available writers for the output format (`"png"`), get a `ImageWriter` from this `Iterator` and then use `addIIOWriteProgressListener` to add a `IIOWriteProgressListener` to it and then use `ImageWriter#setOutput` and pass the `ImageOutputStream` which you created first to it...easy :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have to go now, but should I delete this post because it is a duplicate?

Comment: Probably not a bad idea ;)