# Closing a flash screen in swing

Tags: java, swing, flash

/*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */

```
package newpackage;

import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

/**
 *
 * @author Pavilion
 */
public class Progress extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Progress
     */
    public Progress() {
        initComponents();

        Progressloader pl=new Progressloader(jProgressBar2);

       // try {
        //    pl.join();
       // } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
       // new Homescreen().setVisible(true);
       // }
       //System.exit(0);

        dispose();

    }

   // public  void shut(){
     //   dispose();
    //}

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jProgressBar2 = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(true);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/newpackage/above-progress-bar-image_1.png"))); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 561, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(1, 1, 1))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 320, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        getContentPane().add(jPanel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, -1, 320));

        jProgressBar2.setValue(50);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jProgressBar2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 560, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jProgressBar2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        getContentPane().add(jPanel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 320, 560, 5));

        jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
        jTextArea1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 8)); // NOI18N
        jTextArea1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jTextArea1.setLineWrap(true);
        jTextArea1.setRows(3);
        jTextArea1.setText("XOD SECURE is based on software from XOD Technologies Inc. which has been licensed under the Common Development  and  Distribution License(CDDL)  and  the  GNU  general public license number 2 by the Indian Government. This software has been solely made for the use of the Inadian Police as well as the CPRF. Any use of the software for any other purpose and improper distribution will be an illegal action and serious action will be taken against the person.");
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 560, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 4, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        getContentPane().add(jPanel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 325, 560, 40));

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Progress.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Progress.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Progress.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Progress.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Progress().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar jProgressBar2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}

class Progressloader extends Thread{
    JProgressBar jpb;

    Progressloader(JProgressBar jpb){
        this.jpb=jpb;
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {

        for(int i=jpb.getMinimum();i<=jpb.getMaximum();i++)
        {
            jpb.setValue(i);
            try
            {
            Thread.sleep(20);
            }catch(InterruptedException ex){}

        }
             new Homescreen().setVisible(true);
        //new Progress().setVisible(false);

    }
}
```

What is the problem with this code?The progress bar runs properly and the new window opens but I am not able to dispose the flash screen

Answer (score 2):

You're violating the singe thread rules of Swing to start with, you should be using a `SwingWorker` which provides methods which you can use to safely update the UI from.

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details.

For example:

- [SwingWorker in another SwingWorker's done method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125642/swingworker-in-another-swingworkers-done-method/23126410#23126410)
- [Issues with SwingWorker and JProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835638/issues-with-swingworker-and-jprogressbar/24835935#24835935)

The main problem you have is the fact that your `ProgressLoader` has no reference to your splash screen, so it can't close it.

The `SwingWorker` provides a `PropertyChangeListener` which you can use to monitor the state of the worker, when it's `DONE`, you can use it to close the window

The trick here would be to create the `SwingWorker` from within you "splash screen" and add a `PropertyChangeListener` to before you start it as an anonymous class, this way you could call `dispose` from within the `PropertyChangeListener` when it's done.

As, conceptually, demonstrated here: [Using SwingWorker to add a progress bar in a GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928213/using-swingworker-to-add-a-progress-bar-in-a-gui/14928329#14928329)